# Grails 2.4.5 Resolve error obtaining dependencies

Tags: java, grails, intellij-idea

I am trying to run a cloned grails project into my intellij idea 12.1.4. Here is the error which I get:

```
|Loading Grails 2.4.5
|Configuring classpath
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:tomcat:zip:2.4.5 from/to snapshots_repository_codehaus_org (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org): Gone (410) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:hibernate:zip:2.4.5 from/to snapshots_repository_codehaus_org (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org): Gone (410) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:hibernate:zip:2.4.5 from/to snapshots_repository_codehaus_org (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org): Gone (410) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:tomcat:zip:2.4.5 from/to snapshots_repository_codehaus_org (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org): Gone (410)
```

Has anyone encountered this error? 
And how do I solve this?

Comment: you may check here [link](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org) - The server seems to be down.

Comment: All Codehaus services have now been terminated. From  http://www.codehaus.org/

Comment: maybe you are behind a proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use another servers:

```
mavenRepo "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/"
mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
```